# Output result from one table to update another

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

How can I output t2 to update t3?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../../connection.php");

$sql = mysqli_query(
    $query, 
    "SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        `orders`
    INNER JOIN
        `order_track` ON `orders`.`order_id` = `order_track`.`order_id`
    WHERE
        `order_track`.`t2` = 'inactive'
    ORDER BY
        `orders`.`order_date` DESC"
);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[0]</td>
            <td>$row[1]</td>
            <td>$row[2]</td>
            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onClick=\"approval('".$row[0]."')\">
                    Approve
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>";
}?> 

<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../../connection.php");

$pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];

$sql = mysqli_query(
    $query, 
    "UPDATE
        `order_track`
     SET
         `t2` = 'active'
     WHERE
         `order_id` = '$pid'"
 );

if($sql){
    echo "success";
}?>
```

Comment: i need to change this code manually to be delivered changing t2 to t3. 



`<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("../../../connection.php");

    $pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];

    $sql = mysqli_query($query, "UPDATE `order_track` SET `t2` = 'active' WHERE `order_id` = '$pid'");

    if($sql){
        echo "success";
    }
?>`

Comment: Ok, why don't your attempted changes work? What goes wrong?

Comment: what is the condition for this two to work together. after update t1 to t2. i need to update again t2 to t3.